# How to convert a SVG to a PNG with ImageMagick 6.9.3-8 Q16 version?

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, png

I am trying to convert SVG file (./svgtmp/designsvg.svg) and save as a Png Image (./svgtmp/designsvg.png) with ImageMagick 6.9.3-8 Q16 version. But its not work. after execution convert command $arr returns blank array and $return_var returns 1

```
$svg ='<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="vgroovFrame" width="95" height="95"><polyline id="topLeft" points="0,5 10,5 10,10 5,10 5,0 90,0 90,10 85,10 85,5 95,5 95,90 85,90 85,85 90,85 90,95 5,95 5,85 10,85 10,90 0,90 0,5 " style="fill:#044B9466;stroke:red;stroke-width:1"/></svg>';


    file_put_contents('./svgtmp/designsvg.svg', $svg);


$thumbImg = './svgtmp/designsvg.svg';
$final_img = './svgtmp/designsvg1.png';

$command= "convert -density 500 -resize 128x128 ".$thumbImg."  ".$final_img;
exec("convert -version" ,$arr, $return_var);
```

Comment: Please include your desired and observed behavior, include any debugging information you could gather and the result from your research.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: The error is written to stderr, and will not be present in `$arr` (stdout). Try running the `convert` command directly from CLI, does it complete successfully?

Comment: @emcconville Yes It is completle successful on CLI, but in php it's not working.

Comment: $command= 'convert -size "'.$boundWidth.'"x"'.$boundHeight.'" xc:none -fill none -stroke "'.$vgroovCoreColor.'" -draw "'.$path.'" '.$thumbImage;

     exec($command ,$arr, $return_var);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved using passing path otherwise **ImageMagick 6.9.3-8 Q16** version not allowed to read `.SVG` file

```
$thumbImage = "./actions/tmpsvg/vrgroov_".$_GET['orderId'].".png";
$command= 'convert -size "'.$boundWidth.'"x"'.$boundHeight.'" xc:none -fill none -stroke "'.$vgroovCoreColor.'" -draw "'.$path.'" '.$thumbImage;
exec($command ,$arr, $return_var);
```

If you want to convert `.svg` to `.png` then use **ImageMagick** version **6.9.9 or upgraded**